# ZEBRA label printing

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I need to print labels on my ZEBRA S4M printer.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument { PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings { PrinterName = "ZDesigner S4M-203dpi ZPL" } };
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        pd.Print();
```

And when using Portrait landscape - it's alright, but in Landscape mode I have a big space from the left side of label.. How can I print a horizontal text on my labels?

Thanks a lot.

ADDED

I think that this problem is possible because of small PrintingArea property that I can't change. It's size 300x200 and real paper size is about 200x500...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two options, either try changing your default [paper size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize.aspx), or performing a [translate](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217413).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and write back!

Comment: Ok, I solve this problem by setting printer's paper size property in Windows "Devices and Printers" :)

Comment: I have the same problem, where did you apply this setting?